# Primefaces tooltip for p:selectManyCheckbox or other p:selectMany*/One*

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip

I would like to add a tooltip for each element in a `p:selectManyCheckBox`. However I can't come up with a solution.

I've got a class `Role` that has 3 properties, "id" (Long), "name" (String) and "description" (String). The name is displayed and I would like to have the description as a tooltip.

This is a working piece of code:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" value="#{roleBean.selectedRoles}" converter="roleConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{roleBean.roles}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.name}" itemValue="#{role}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

The `roleConverter` is a `FacesConverter` that converts the `Role` to an id and visa versa.

I came up with this:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" value="#{roleBean.selectedRoles}" converter="roleConverter">
    <c:forEach var="role" items="#{roleBean.roles}">
        <f:selectItem id="role#{role.id}" itemLabel="#{role.name}" itemValue="#{role}" />
        <p:tooltip for="role#{role.id}" value="#{role.description}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [`SelectItem#getDescription()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html#getDescription()) property as below:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection"
    value="#{roleBean.selectedRoles}" converter="roleConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{roleBean.roles}" var="role" 
        itemValue="#{role}" itemLabel="#{role.name}" 
        itemDescription="#{role.description}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

This is supported since PrimeFaces 6.2 ([actually because of this very answer you're reading now](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2992)).

In case you're not on PrimeFaces 6.2 yet and cannot upgrade for some reason, then you need to manually override the PrimeFaces `SelectManyCheckboxRenderer#encodeOptionLabel()` as below in order to recognize and render it:

```
public class YourSelectManyCheckboxRenderer extends SelectManyCheckboxRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void encodeOptionLabel(FacesContext context, SelectManyCheckbox checkbox, String containerClientId, SelectItem option, boolean disabled) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("label", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("for", containerClientId, null);

        if (option.getDescription() != null) {
            writer.writeAttribute("title", option.getDescription(), null);
        }

        if (disabled) {
            writer.writeAttribute("class", "ui-state-disabled", null);
        }

        if (option.isEscape()) {
            writer.writeText(option.getLabel(), null);
        } else {
            writer.write(option.getLabel());
        }

        writer.endElement("label");
    }

}
```

Which is registered as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.SelectManyCheckboxRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.YourSelectManyCheckboxRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tooltip support for selectManyCheckbox was [added](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2992) since Primefaces v6.2 version. Other components support this too.

XHTML code is the same BalusC reported

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection" value="#{roleBean.selectedRoles}" converter="roleConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{roleBean.roles}" var="role" 
        itemValue="#{role}" itemLabel="#{role.name}" itemDescription="#{role.description}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

but is not anymore required override the PrimeFaces SelectManyCheckboxRenderer

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify BalusC's solution to make it work in my case. That is beacause I had to build the List of SelectItems on the Bean-side.

```
public List<SelectItem> getMyItems(){
  List<SelectItem> mySelectItems = new ArrayList<>();
  [loop or ohter code to collect items]
  // create SelectItem with description
  mySelectItems.add(new SelectItem([value], [label], [description]));
  ...
  return mySelectItems;
}
```

Then these SelectItems can be used with:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myItems}"/>
```

Comment: Mandator/client and access rights specific SelectItems. Better code doing that at the Bean-side than in xhtml.