# <f:selectItems itemDescription> does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I have there code

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="starter" value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.starter}" style="width:160px" converter="#{reportStarterConverter}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Report Starter" itemValue="0"
itemDescription="TEST" />
<f:selectItems
value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems}" var="ds" itemLabel="#{ds.name}" itemValue="#{ds}" itemDescription="#{ds.description}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

here `itemDescription="TEST"` atribute works very well in `<f:selectItem>` tag. but `itemDescription="#{ds.description}"`  not working in `<f:selectItems>` tag.

is here bug?

Comment: i think is bean problem .
may be you need to rebuild you project .

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ ?

Comment: i use mave and now i clean and install project but not working. Why works itemDescription="TEST" in <f:selectItem> tag and why not working  in <f:selectItems> ?

Comment: Not a description of the screen...I want to show the description of the mouse brought in all...

Comment: Is the `itemLabel="#{ds.name}"` working fine ?

Comment: yes works very well. if i m try to write itemDescription="test test" e.g plain text this is not works. I think here is <f:selectItems> bug.

Comment: is here any solution to show description?

Comment: post your bean code, particularly reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems

Comment: Please elaborate "not working" in developer's terms instead of in enduser's terms. What exactly happens (not)?

Comment: You mean, the **tooltip of the option** is not being shown? Well, in that case this answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780397/primefaces-tooltip-for-pselectmanycheckbox/12512353#12512353

Comment: public List<SelectItem> startersSelectItems;   startersSelectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
startersSelectItems.add(new SelectItem(ds, ds.getName())); this is bean class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f:selectItems requires a List which you define in our bean like this:

```
List<SelectItem> list = new LinkedList<SelectItem>();
list.add(new SelectItem("this will be the return value -> itemValue", "this will be the display value -> itemLable"));
```

If you do so, you don't even need itemValue or itemDescription, because it's already defined in the list.

**Update(note: you don't need itemValue, itemDescription):**

In your xhtml page it would look like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.starter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: I have   startersSelectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(); startersSelectItems.add(new SelectItem(ds, ds.getName())); i try to use ds.getName() to show itemDescription="#{ds.name}" but not working

Comment: Did you remove itemDescription, itemLabel from your f:selectItems tag? I updated my answer, try it.

Comment: no, i have converter and other attribute in <p:selectOneMenu>. is any difference between  new LinkedList<SelectItem>() and new ArrayList<SelectItem>()?