# JSF <ui:repeat> component

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to make simple DropDownList.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="starter" value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.starter}" style="width:160px" converter="#{reportStarterConverter}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select Report Starter">
                           <ui:repeat value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems}" var="dss">
                                <f:selectItem  itemLabel="#{dss}" itemValue="#{dss}" itemDescription="TEST" />
                           </ui:repeat>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

`DropDownList` is enpty, if i use `<f:selectItems>` instead of `<ui:repeat>` works very well, but `<f:selectItems>` Component `itemDescription`=(this is simple tooltip analogy) not working. `<f:selectItem>` Component `itemDescription`=(this is simple tooltip analogy) working fine. That's why I decided to use the  and `<f:selectItem>` with its `itemDescription` attribute.

Comment: DropDownList is enpty, if i use <f:selectItems> instead of <ui:repeat> works very well, but <f:selectItems> Component itemDescription=(this is simple tooltip analogy) not working. <f:selectItem> Component itemDescription=(this is simple tooltip analogy) working fine. That's why I decided to use the <ui:repeat> and <f:selectItem> with its itemDescription attribute.

Comment: No need to post your question as comment, [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15700316/edit) you question instead

Comment: i'm try to ubdate but not updatede. there words <f:selectItems>  not copi in original post

Comment: I update your question with your comments, verify it and approve it.

Comment: Which field contains the list that you want to display in the DropDownList ? `reportRegisterManagedBean.starter` or `reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems` ?

Comment: reportRegisterManagedBean.starter is one component. reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems is list off reportRegisterManagedBean.starter components

Comment: I want to use <ui:repeat>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27163/discussion-between-zuri-and-apurv)

Comment: Sorry, no access to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27163/discussion-between-zuri-and-apurv) from _my company_ :(

Comment: ok, have you used  <ui:repeat> component in jsf?

Comment: why do you want to use ui:repeat? post your bean code reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems

Comment: Because, <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Report Starter" itemValue="0" itemDescription="TEST" /> here itemDescription="TEST" (tooltip) works and <f:selectItems value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems}" var="ds" itemLabel="#{ds.name}" itemValue="#{ds}" itemDescription="#{ds.name}" /> itemDescription="#{ds.name}" now working here.

Comment: what primefaces version you using? My example is with 3.5

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.2</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:selectItem>` needs to be added during view build time. However, the `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time. You need a repeater which runs during view build time. The JSTL `<c:forEach>` is such one.

```html
<p:selectOneMenu ...>
    <c:forEach items="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems}" var="dss">
        <f:selectItem ... />
    </c:forEach>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Alternatively, create a custom renderer. Here's an example which does exactly the same for `<p:selectManyCheckbox>`: [Primefaces tooltip for p:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780397/primefaces-tooltip-for-pselectmanycheckbox/12512353#12512353)

Comment: i have included there components in my xhtml file. <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> how to add jstl?

Comment: Just add `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: <p:selectOneMenu id="starter" value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.starter}" style="width:160px" converter="#{reportStarterConverter}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select Report Starter">
                           <c:forEach value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems}" var="dss">
                                <f:selectItem  itemLabel="#{dss}" itemValue="#{dss}" itemDescription="TEST" />
                           </c:forEach>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  my converter throws error java.lang.NullPointerException
 at

Comment: BalusC This is due to the fact that, tooltip not working, <h:outputText value="Starter" />
      <p:selectOneMenu id="starter" value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.starter}" style="width:160px" converter="#{reportStarterConverter}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select Report Starter">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Report Starter" itemValue="0" itemDescription="TEST" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.startersSelectItems}" var="ds" itemLabel="#{ds.name}" itemValue="#{ds}" itemDescription="#{ds.name}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>

Answer (score 2):

As you don't like String array.
here is tested and working example with User class:

```
public class FilterBean {

private List<User> uList = new ArrayList<User>();
private User selectedUser = new User();


public List<User> getuList() {
    User u1 = new User();
    u1.setName("Tom");
    u1.setDesc("worker");
    User u2 = new User();
    u2.setName("Peter");
    u2.setDesc("owner");

    uList.add(u1);
    uList.add(u2);

    return uList;
}

public void setuList(List<User> uList) {
    this.uList = uList;
}   

public User getSelectedUser() {
    return selectedUser;
}

public void setSelectedUser(User selectedUser) {
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
}
}
```

And this is JSF

```
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{filterBean.selectedUser}"> 
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />   
        <f:selectItems  value="#{filterBean.uList}" var="n" itemValue="#{n}" itemDescription="#{n.desc}" itemLabel="#{n.name}" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

This shows desc for Tom and Peter :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you create a drop-down list in `primefaces`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="starter" value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.starter.selectedItem}">  
        <f:selectItems value="#{reportRegisterManagedBean.starter.startersSelectItems}" />  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: this works but <f:selectItems> component itemDescription="" not working, and <f:selectItem> itemDescription="" works,  That's why I decided to use the <ui:repeat> and <f:selectItem> with its itemDescription attribute.

Comment: When `itemDescription` is used with `f:selectItems`, it needs a `List`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15609873/960778) has a solution for your problem

Comment: public List<SelectItem> startersSelectItems; this is list

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several examples and got this results:

I have this in pojo:

```
private String selectL;
private String[] listas;


public String[] getListas() {
    listas = new String[2];  
    listas[0] = "pirmas";
    listas[1] = "antras";
    return listas;
}
```

and this jsf works (itemDescription must be String):

```
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{formBean.selectL}">   
        <f:selectItems  value="#{filterBean.listas}" var="n" itemDescription="#{n}2" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

and this not :/ :

```
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{formBean.selectL}">   
        <f:selectItems  value="#{filterBean.listas}" itemDescription="test2" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

EDIT:

After some test I just added var into second selectOneMenu and it WORKS now too:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{formBean.selectL}">   
        <f:selectItems  value="#{filterBean.listas}" var="n" itemDescription="test2" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: itemDescription="test2" this works well? i want to dinamically tooltip, e.i. #{ds.name} and #{ds.description} and this is realized only SelectItem in list

Comment: for me itemDescription="#{n}2" and itemDescription="test2" works fine now. Tested on IE, FF and chome.

Comment: ok, but i want to list, because in my list i have put hibernate entity, and how to put entity in String array, this is bad idea

Comment: I dont think u need to put this into String array. This is just example. Just this ds.name should be as String.