# PrimeFaces - Tooltip in a SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip

I'm trying to use tooltip in a `p:selectOneMenu`.

I need to show different information tooltip for each option in the `f:selectItem` when you do a mouse over or just "pre-select" the option.

What I want:
[image: What i want]

I have the information need for it in the same list that I'm using for the OneSelectMenu, but I tried with the basic `<p:tooltip>` and the `<f:facet name="itemtip">` from:

[image: Itemtip]

and nothing works.

What you can recommend me to do? 
Im using PrimeFaces 6.1.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use the attribute `itemDescription`.

Here is a working working example tested with PF 6.1 (Joinfaces jsf-spring-boot-starter), Firefox, Chrome, IE and even Edge:

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuTooltipView.cars}" var="car"
        itemLabel="#{car.name}" itemValue="#{car}"
        itemDescription="#{car.desc}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

[image: p:selectOneMenu tooltip]

Comment: @MauricioMoralesOsorio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780397/primefaces-tooltip-for-pselectmanycheckbox

Comment: @MauricioMoralesOsorio please provide your code then, i reproduced this example before answering your question. I've now added a working example. And why did I get a downvote?